# .NET piaryProvider VS the regular .NET System.Net.WebRequest

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

Just started to work with ApiAry as a client/consumer and I’m wondering what is the best way to do it.

Should I use the regular .NET System.Net.WebRequest or  ApiaryProvider (http://fsprojects.github.io/ApiaryProvider/) and why?

If someone can help with a sample C# code it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To get started you can use any .NET HTTP library. A specialized library is not necessary. For some code examples in C#, you can use the sample API for your account to access C# sample code. If you have turned on the new documentation in Beta (set in settings on the API), you can click on an action for the API in the documentation view and select C# in the language selector on the right.

Otherwise, in the original documentation view, click on a URL and choose a language in the selector that is available when the documentation expands for the particular URL to get sample code.